# What is cause of this error in android app - Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed

Tags: java, android, android-ndk-r5

My android app continuously gets the channel broken error and this closes down app automatecally. On log only following two lines will be prited in red

```
  ERROR/InputDispatcher(2687): channel '40561dd8 com.mypackage.myActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x801-09
  ERROR/InputDispatcher(2687): channel '40561dd8 com.mypackage.myActivity  (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

App targets Android 2.2 platform version.

Request you to help me getting cause of this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am encountering the same error and I started wondering if maybe my app does not get shut down because of that error message, but that the message appears because my app gets shutdown (possibly for some other reason - that however does not appear in the logfile...)

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem for myself and working on a solution.

What i can say so far is that its connected to WebView (at least in my case) and the InputDispatcher is a native library of android written in C++.

The seems to be occuring because the Thread handling the connection is getting into a locked state because of some kind of error.

Here is the Source to the Dispatcher ->

http://gitorious.org/rowboat/frameworks-base/blobs/b27b8c0caf8ff23d10eea655085769f314050427/libs/ui/InputDispatcher.cpp

I dont know which android version its serving but you find the origin of your error message at the roundabout 1860th line.

I know this is no solution but it might help you out gettin behind it.